# bash script single quote and backslash creation

Tags: bash, syntax

I'm trying to write a bash script for a snapshot backup with rsync to a server.

The command I want to invoke is

```
rsync -aPh -e ssh --rsync-path='sudo rsync' --link-dest=../last /home/username/files remoteuser@server:/srv/backups/snapshots/username/snapshot_xxx
```

my script looks like

```
OPT="-aPh -e ssh --rsync-path='sudo rsync'"
LINK="--link-dest=../last/" 
SRC="/home/username/files/"
SNAP="remoteuser@server:/srv/backups/snapshots/username/"
date=`date "+%Y-%b-%d_%T"`

# Run rsync to create snapshot
rsync $OPT $LINK $SRC ${SNAP}$date
```

running this script with bash -x the command I'm getting is

```
rsync -aPh -e ssh '--rsync-path='\''sudo' 'rsync'\''' --link-dest=../last /home/username/files remoteuser@server:/srv/backups/snapshots/username/snapshot_xxx
```

which leads to the following errors:

bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

How do I prevent bash from inserting the extra single quotes and escaped single quotes?

Comment: Can you please share exactly how you are running the script? normally, `-c` would not be used

Comment: I'm just typing in the name of the script which is located in /usr/local/bin in that case I enter snapbackupremote.sh for the output I showed in my question i did run bash -x /usr/local/bin/snapbackupremote.sh

Comment: sorry copy/paste error since i use the script local as well, i have corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't insert extra quotes, you did, here:

```
OPT="-aPh -e ssh --rsync-path='sudo rsync'"
                              ^          ^
```

That assignment sets `OPT` to the string `-aPh -e ssh --rsync-path='sudo rsync'`. When that's expanded in the `rsync` command line, it gets split on the whitespace to five different arguments: `aPh`, `-e`, `ssh` `--rsync-path='sudo` and `rsync'`.

The `'\''` things you see in the output of `bash -x` are a representation of those arguments containing quotes . It's a bit hard to read, but `'foo'\''bar'` is the single-quoted equivalent of `"foo'bar"` (it has two single-quoted strings, and an escaped single quote in the middle.)

Quotes don't work after a variable is expanded, you can't store a command with arguments containing whitespace in a simple variable, you'll need to use an array instead.

See:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)

Comment: reading the two articles you metntioned in your answer, I can't figure out which syntax i need to use to get the correct syntax for my command. The call needs to be --rsync-path='sudo rsync' the single quotes are needed, the best thing i can come up with is using an array like OPT=(-aPh -e ssh '--rsync-path='\''sudo rsync'\') i tried different variants none worked, I am calling the function with rsync ${OPT[@]} $LINK $SRC ${SNAP}$date, maybe you can tell me the correct syntax for this very case

Comment: @peter, I don't think you need to pass the quotes to rsync. When you write `rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync"` on the shell command line, what the quotes do is tell the shell that the space is supposed to be part of the string passed to rsync. What rsync sees is just the argument `--rsync-path=sudo rsync`. It knows how to remove the part up to the equal sign and treat the rest as the command. In an array, you'd pass that as `( ... --rsync-path="sudo rsync" ... )`, or `( ... '--rsync-path=sudo rsync' ... )` or whatever.

Comment: `'--rsync-path='\''sudo rsync'\'` would pass the quotes to `rsync`, which then passes  the command `'sudo rsync'` to the shell, which would then look for a command called `sudo rsync` in the path. (That's different from running the command `sudo` with an argument of `rsync`, which would happen if the shell just got the command `sudo rsync`). For example, on my machine, `rsync -av '--rsync-path="sudo rsync"' -e ssh y localhost:/tmp/z` gives the error `bash: sudo rsync: command not found`.

Comment: @ikkachu comment1 neither `OPT=(-aPh -e ssh '--rsync-path=sudo rsync')` nor `OPT=(-aPh -e ssh --rsync-path="sudo rsync")` does work, this yields to an error: `sudo: unrecognized option '--server'`, the same thing happens if I run the command manually. However running the command manually with either single or double quotes around sudo rsync does work

Comment: @ikkachu comment2 passing sudo rsync works just fine, this runs rsync on the server with sudo, which I need since the directory I need to backup to is only writeable by root, and on the remote machine i allow the remoteuser to run rsync via sudo without a password `remotesuer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync`. Running this command `rsync -aPh -e ssh --rsync-path='sudo rsync' --link-dest=../last /home/username/files remoteuser@server:/srv/backups/snapshots/username/snapshot_xxx`on my machnie just works fine but i can't get it to run from a script

Comment: @peter, yes, I rechecked the manual, rsync passes the argument to `--rsync-path` through a shell, so yeah, `sudo rsync` works there. (That just makes the option oddly named, but nevermind that.)

Comment: It looks to me that you're missing the quotes around the array expansion. You need `rsync "${OPT[@]}" ...`, not `rsync ${OPT[@]} ...`. Without the quotes, the contents of the array get word-split again, and then it's the same as running `rsync ... --rsync-path=sudo rsync ...` on the command line (that is, the `sudo` and `rsync` aren't part of the same argument)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. The quotes around the array expression finally solved the problem